# Why led turning on when switch is low in pic starter kit?

Tags: led, pic, switches, kits

I have a [**PIC starter kit**](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/images/mchpsiteimages/PIC32%20USB%20Starter%20Kit%20II.gif). I am doing a simple program of turning on led when switch is pressed and then turning them off when switch is released like following:

```
if(switch==1)
{
  led = 1;
}
else
{
  led = 0;
}
```

I was actually not able to do above code in MPLAB. Then I found a tutorial online. I used that code and it was working.

```
Switch is connected to RD7
Led is connected to RD0
```

**CODE**

```
if(PORTAbits.RD7 == 0) 
{
  PORTDbits.RD0 = 1;
}
else if(PORTAbits.RD7 == 1)
{
  PORTDbits.RD0 = 0;
}
```

Now I am confused. Why led is turning on when **`switch(RD7)`** is low. Can anyone explain me this logic.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer to the [User Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61158A.pdf). It says that

> Push button switches provide the following functionality:
>
> • SW1: Active-low switch connected to RD6
>
> • SW2: Active-low switch connected to RD7
>
> • SW3: Active-low switch connected to RD13

also

> The switches do not have any debounce circuitry and require the use of internal pull-up
> resistors; this allows you to investigate software debounce techniques.

So I think this answers your question of why led is turning on when switch(RD7) is low

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the documentation for your board](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61158A.pdf), you will see the following, which I think is self explanatory:

[image: doc]